# Count occurrences of specific value in column based on categories of another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Categories | Clicks 
1          |   1
1          |   3
1          |   2
2          |   2 
2          |   1
2          |   1
2          |   2
3          |   1
3          |   2
3          |   3
4          |   2
4          |   1
```

And to make some bar plots I would like for it to look like this:

```
Categories | Clicks_count | Clicks_prob
1          |  1           |  33%
2          |  2           |  50%
3          |  1           |  33%
4          |  1           |  50%
```

so basically: grouping by `Categories` and calculating on `Clicks_count` the number of times per category that `Clicks` takes the value 1, and `Clicks_prob` the probability of `Clicks` taking the value 1 (so it's  count of Clicks==1/Count of Category i observations)

How could I do this? I tried, to get the second column:

```
df.groupby("Categories")["Clicks"].count().reset_index()
```

but the result is:

```
Categories | Clicks 
1          | 3
2          | 4
3          | 3
4          | 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sum` and `mean` on the condition `Clicks==1`. Since you're working with groups, put them in groupby:

```
df['Clicks'].eq(1).groupby(df['Categories']).agg(['sum','mean'])
```

Output:

```
            sum      mean
Categories               
1             1  0.333333
2             2  0.500000
3             1  0.333333
4             1  0.500000
```

To match output's naming, use named aggregation:

```
df['Clicks'].eq(1).groupby(df['Categories']).agg(Click_counts='sum', Clicks_prob='mean')
```

Output:

```
            Click_counts  Clicks_prob
Categories                           
1                      1     0.333333
2                      2     0.500000
3                      1     0.333333
4                      1     0.500000
```

Comment: That works great! I realise I forgot to add another column I need: the count of observations per Category (for Cat 1 it would be 3, Cat 2 would be 4, etc). Is there a way to add it?

Comment: Yes, add `'count'` together with the other two functions `'mean'` and `'sum'`.

Comment: so easy, you're right. I have to study about the groupby().agg() functions clearly. Thank you!